# Test to determine if Facebook link is a fan page or personal

Tags: facebook, url, testing

I am attempting to allow users to supply me with their facebook link when registering and when their profile is created, I auto populate a facebook like box into their profile.  The problem I am having is that the like box does not work with personal facebook pages.

I need a way to test if a url is a fan page or personal page before displaying so I don't get an error on my page.  The only way I've been able to test so far is using php strpos to search for the string "pages/" which is in many fan page urls.  If anyone can help me out with a concrete way to determine which page a url leads to, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/), may be a way to solve this problem.

If you compare the [`User`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) and the [`Page`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) object, you will notice that there are some unique fields. For example a page has `likes`.

Now you only need to make a HTTP request to the Graph API and check if the response contains a specific field e.g. `likes`.

User: https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor

Page: https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola

Comment: @DinkyDana Don't forget to accept this as answer ;-) - Just click on the tick. Glad it worked for you!